# ember.js multimodel forms: what is expected from ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have classic multimodel form: a transport document that has many transport_document_rows, as stated in my MODELS:

```
App.TransportDocument = DS.Model.extend
  number: DS.attr 'string'
  date: DS.attr 'string'
  transportDocumentRows: DS.hasMany('App.TransportDocumentRow')

App.TransportDocumentRow = DS.Model.extend
  productName: DS.attr 'string'
  quantity: DS.attr 'string'
  transportDocument: DS.belongsTo('App.TransportDocument')
```

I write in console this script:

```
a = App.Invoice.createRecord();
a.get("invoiceRows").pushObject(App.InvoiceRow.createRecord());
a.get("store").commit();
```

And the problem is the following:

- My transport document is created correctly
- My transport document row is created SEQUENTLY (and it could still be not a problem) but with a wrong transport_document_id (transport_document_id: 0).

Is this behaviour expected?
What could I do to correct it?

Thanks

EDIT:
the only way it works is using  the embedded option:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map 'App.TransportDocument', {
  transportDocumentRows: { embedded: 'always' }
}
```

This options commits the transport document and its rows in a single HTTP request.

This requires changing the GET response, including the `transport_document_rows` content direcly in the `transport_documents` key of the response hash

Comment: do you have any extra config for this associations like: `DS.WhicheverAdapterYoureUsing.map('App.TransportDocument', { transportDocumentRows: { embedded: 'load' } });` ?

Comment: No, nothing like that

Comment: The correct behavior would be transportDocumentRows having the fresh and correct transport_document_id ?

Comment: Not quite sure. I'm actually struggling with a similar scenario myself. In my case, it seems that I'll have to do it in multiple steps: Commit the parent, then the children.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe i have a partial solution if you need, see edit