# ember-data: server side code for removing an associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, ember-rails

I 'm working with revision 12 of ember-data RESTAdapter and using the rails-api gem.

I have these models:

```
App.TransportDocumentRow = DS.Model.extend,
  productName: DS.attr 'string'
  transportDocument: DS.belongsTo('App.TransportDocument')

App.TransportDocument = DS.Model.extend
  number: DS.attr 'string'
  transportDocumentRows: DS.hasMany('App.TransportDocumentRow')
```

configured in this way:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map 'App.TransportDocument', {
  transportDocumentRows: { embedded: 'always' }
}
```

(i'm using `embedded: always` becauseif i don't my document rows are committed with document_id = 0, as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466327/ember-js-multimodel-forms-what-is-expected-from-ember-data)

Consider i have already created a transport document (id: 1) with 2 rows. If i delete a row (with id: 1), the result would be a PUT request to `/transport_documents/1`.

The JSON sent with this put would be something like this:

```
{"transport_document"=>
  {"number"=>"1", "transport_document_rows"=>
    [
      {"id"=>2, "product_name"=>"aaaa", "transport_document_id"=>1}
    ]
  }, "id"=>"1"
}
```

while rails would expect something like this:

```
{"transport_document"=>
  {"number"=>"1", "transport_document_rows"=>
    [
      {"id"=>1, "_delete"=>1}
      {"id"=>2, "product_name"=>"aaaa", "transport_document_id"=>1}
    ]
  }, "id"=>"1"
}
```

Is there a way specified in active_model_serializers to do this?
Or should i make some manual transformations my controller?
Or should i change the payload so that ember produces the correct request?